# solr-tomcat package on ubuntu lucid

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, solr, package

I've installed solr-tomcat package on ubuntu lucid (10.04 latest).
It automatically install java and tomcat and hopefully all other dependencies.
I can access tomcat at http://localhost:8080 but not sure where to find the solr web admin
http://localhost:8180 gives me nothing.

Is this package known to work? I've read that on previous ubuntu releases the packages were broken.
Do I need to configure anything after installing the package?

Thanks

Comment: try posting this on http://www.serverfault.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

looking at the contained solr-tomcat.xml i see a line

```
...
<Context path="/solr" docBase="/usr/share/solr"
...
```

so i would guess you find it http://localhost:8080/solr

Hope that helps.